# Use Counter cache for HABTM association in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-model

I have two Tables:
it is defined as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users_correlations` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `correlated_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `role` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `gender` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `dob` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `location` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `photo` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `photo_dir` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `about_me` tinytext,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  `follower_count`  INT DEFAULT 0,
  `following_count` INT DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=42 ;
```

Now i defined HABTM association as follow:

```
 public $hasAndBelongsToMany=array(

      'Following'=>array(
               'className'=>'User',
               'joinTable'=>'users_correlations',
               'ForeignKey'=>'correlated_id',
               'associationForeignKey' => 'user_id'
       ),
       'Followers'=>array(
                'className'=>'User',
                'joinTable'=>'users_correlations',
                'ForeignKey'=>'user_id',
                'associationForeignKey' => 'correlated_id'
        )
    );
```

Now i want to implemnt Countercache to track record of number of followers and following..

I use ConterCacheHabtm behavior  for my model referred by

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/danaki/2009/05/29/counter-cache-behavior-for-habtm-relations

but for my association it is not updating my follower_count and following_count.
Please Help in this scenario.

Comment: This looks fine. Can you post the code you use for your `find` operation?

Comment: `$this->User->find('first');`

Answer (score 0):

```
 'Followers'=>array(
            'className'=>'User',
            'joinTable'=>'users_correlations',
            'ForeignKey'=>'user_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'correlated_id',
            'counterCache' => true
        )
```

You need to add the `'counterCache' => true` to the array. The rest looks like it should work fine.